# How to place contour plot in specific coordinate?

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I would to like ask about how to plot a contour in specific coordinate?  I already searched for an example of a contour plot and I have this.  Here is the code:

```
r = 0.15;  
rx = -r:0.01:r;
ry = r:-0.01:-r;
[x_coor, y_coor] = meshgrid(rx, ry);
radius = sqrt(x_coor.^2+y_coor.^2);
contourf(x_coor,y_coor, radius,'edgecolor','none');
xlabel('Widht');
ylabel('Long');
```

...and the result is:

[image]

I want the center of the contour plot placed at a specific coordinate.  For example `X = 10` and `Y = 10`.  How do I put the coordinate in the code?

Comment: I have edited your code as it did not run due to the undefined `x` and `y` variables.  That has changed in the above code to `x_coor` and `y_coor`.  Your code now reproduces the plot shown in the figure.  I have also answered your question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.  Place an offset within the `contourf` command.  In other words:

```
xMove = 10;
yMove = 10;
contourf(x_coor + xMove, y_coor + yMove, radius,'edgecolor','none');
```

`xMove` and `yMove` are whichever offsets in the `x` and `y` direction you want.  Given your example co-ordinates, you thus get:

[image: contour]

Good luck!

Comment: i've problem when i add xlim and ylim or axis in that code sir? example xlim([0 30]), ylim([0 30]) or axis([0 30 0 30]). the contour plot doesn't appear, what should i do?

Comment: When you're doing the limit commands you are stretching the viewing window so that it spans from 0 to 30 in both directions. However your radius is too small which is why you don't see anything. Change your radius to something larger... Like 15. Set `r` to 15 in that code or something substantially more.

Comment: it works sir, but there is blank space in the contour plot if i use 15, and i try >15 with 0.01 the plot doesn't appear so i change  0.01 to 0.1, the result http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Kaito_Aokage/Capture1_zpsb22564c1.png?t=1402672247 thanks for help sir :) sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Kaito - You're very welcome.  Glad to see that it works